# VCard Attachment in mail

Tags: objective-c

how to attach the vcard in mail client programmatically, want to create a .vcf file and attach to the mail client

Answer (score 1):

You can find the person and get the vCard in an NSData object with ABPerson. You might need to write that data to some temporary NSURL, but then you can instruct Mail to create and send an email using a scripting bridge. There's some pretty nifty [sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SBSendEmail/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10004645-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) that looks like it will do just what you need after some slight modification.

Comment: I couldn't post more than one link because I'm new to SO, but ABPerson is here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Reference/AddressBook/Classes/ABPerson_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/ABPerson and you can read more about how there really isn't a more direct option here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa2004/qa1084.html